# How to bind a directory between Guest OS and Docker container?

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-volume

The environment is a Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS virtual machine running inside VirtualBox on my Windows 10 PC.

The issue I'm having is when I run the docker image and use the '-v' flag to bind a directory in Ubuntu to the docker container, I don't receive any errors but any changes in the directory are not reflected in the container.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this?

For reference, when in the project directory, this is the command I attempt to run

```
sudo docker run -v $PWD/src:/src -p 80:80 getting-started
```

Where src contains the following php file which I attempt to modify to see changes:

```
<?php
echo "Hello, World!";
```

The dockerfile used to create the image contains the following:

```
FROM php:apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

Also having navigated into the docker container terminal I cannot see the folder I mounted.

Comment: try this ./src:/src

Comment: I've attempted with correct absolute path and is still not working.

Comment: Once you start the container exec into it and then find the path to the directory you are trying to bind. Put that in the second part of -v

Comment: That doesn't work either unfortunately. I believe its an issue relating to the virtual machine and the docker containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was executing the docker run command as sudo which meant that as a normal user I couldn't edit the folder and therefore no changes were ever propagated.

To resolve I just added my normal non root user to the docker group restarted the VM and tried the run command with directory bind again and it worked worked perfectly!

The following command adds a user to the docker group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

replace $USER with your user name

For more information see: [Add non root user to docker group](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)

Answer (score 0):

Docker interpreted the `/src:/src` as mounting the directory `/src` at the root of your host's filesystem to your container's `/src` directory.

From your Dockerfile, it looks like you want to mount `src` in the local directory.

**EDIT:** From comments below, I had the wrong `-v` syntax initially. Instead, you need to use an absolute path. You can accomplish this with the commands below

```sh
sudo docker run -v $PWD/src:/src -p 80:80 getting-started
```

See [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) about bind mounts.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, I've tried both your suggestions but unfortunately this doesn't resolve my issue. I don't believe it's an issue with the path but something related to the Ubuntu virtual machine and docker containers.

Comment: The `docker run -v` option always takes an absolute path.  Your second option mounts a named volume `src` on to the container `/src` directory, which is very different.  Do you mean `-v $PWD/src:/src`?

Comment: I've just given that a go as well but even with the absolute path correctly specified it doesn't work. I'm thinking it must be something to do with the virtual machine? Works fine running docker inside windows.

Comment: @ThomasFinch Does [this issue](https://forums.docker.com/t/bind-mounts-empty-in-docker-toolbox/78780) seem to match your issue and how you installed Docker in VBox? The solution doesn't seem to be ideal (downgrading VBox) but it seems like a similar issue.

Comment: I've had a read through and although similar I'm not sure that is related to my issue. I'm not using Docker Toolbox. Do you think I need to make the src folder a shared virtual box folder?